# How do I switch elastic IPs on a Linux AWS without getting disconnected from XShell?

Tags: ruby, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using XShell to access a Linux AWS. I know how to switch elastic IP addresses with Ruby, but when I do, XShell's connection to the AWS gets busted.

Here's `script.rb` I run on the AWS via XShell with the `ruby script.rb` command:

```
require 'json'
require 'pp'

region = 'REGION NAME'
aws_access_key_id = 'SECRET KEY ID'
aws_secret_access_key = 'SECRET ACCESS KEY'
credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
client = Aws::EC2::Client.new(
    region: region,
    credentials: credentials
)
pp client
p '==='

describeAddresses = `aws ec2 describe-addresses`
awsHash = JSON.parse(describeAddresses)
pp awsHash
p '==='

getInstanceID = `wget -O - 'http://MY.AWS.IP.HERE/latest/meta-data/instance-id' 2>/dev/null`
instanceID = getInstanceID.split("\n")[-1]
pp instanceID
p '==='

resp = client.allocate_address({
  domain: "vpc", # accepts vpc, standard
})
pp resp
p '==='

resp2 = client.associate_address({
    instance_id: instanceID,
    allocation_id: resp['allocation_id'],
    allow_reassociation: true#,
})
pp resp2
p '==='
```

Comment: you're trying to replace your shoes will standing in them. you can't keep the connection alive, because you're changing the IP you'd originally connected to. tcp has no provision for changing IPs in the middle of a connection like that.

Comment: @MarcB Hmm. If I want to write a webcrawler to switch IPs occasionally, is this possible with the sort of code I have in my post?

Comment: a better setup would be one permanent IP for your login/scrip session, and then a second changeable IP that your crawler uses for the crawl stuff.

Comment: @MarcB I need to be able to switch IPs every so often. So I'd need more than two IP addresses available...